# MySQL select query with parameter

Tags: c#, mysql, select

I am trying to use MYSQL select query with c#.

Following query for searching "ID" is working fine:

```
conn = new MySqlConnection(cs);
conn.Open();
cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "select * from catalog_product_entity where entity_id = ?Id";
MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
cmd.Parameters.Add("?Id", SqlDbType.Text).Value = ProductList[i].ProductId.ToString();
adp.Fill(MagentoProduct);
```

Now, I want to search exact string value in table. I am using following code and its giving empty result:

My Code:

```
                            conn = new MySqlConnection(cs);
                            conn.Open();
                            cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from catalog_category_entity_varchar where value = @Value;", conn);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", "Storybooks");
                            MySqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                            while (r.Read())
                            {
                                log.WriteEntry(r.GetString("value"));
                            }
```

Comment: What does "giving an error" mean? Make sure to include the *exact* error message and/or accurate problem description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try SQL Reader

```
c = new MySqlCommand("select * from catalog_product_entity where column_nam = @Value;", conn);
c.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", your string);
MySqlDataReader r = c.ExecuteReader();
```

and then use Reader methods like reader.GetString("column_name"), ....

Comment: HI BlaugranaGent, I just tried your code. No error but the result is still empty. I am not what is wrong.

Comment: Well, it is good practise to use parameters because it gives you some protection against SQL Injection. I am not sure why result is empty, you should see in database are there any queries. Also, you could paste the exact command that is not working so I could tell you more

Answer (score 3):

This is the problem:

```
where value = '?cname'
```

That's specifying `?cname` as the literal value you're searching for - when you *actually* just want the parameter. Remove the quotes and it should be fine:

```
where value = ?cname
```

(You should use `using` statements for the connection and command, mind you...)

Comment: @user2864740: True - unless it detected that a parameter had been passed but not specified?

Comment: I just changed "where value = '?cname'" to "where value = ?cname".

Comment: @user3685232: Right, and? (You should edit your post to say *what* error you were receiving, by the way.)