# C# partial data display from MYSQL database

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a MYSQL Database which stores Data about guests in a TV show.  the following command needs to be applied :

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(
@"select  
   guest.name,
   guest.occupation,
   guest.pv,
   guest.phone,
   guest.mobile,
   guest.email,
   program.name,
   episode.date, 
   episode.time  
from 
   guest,
   program,
   host,
   episode 
where guest.name=episode.guestnamefk
 AND host.name=episode.hostnamefk 
 AND program.name=episode.programnamefk
 AND  guest.name  Like '%" + searchnamebox.Text + "%' ", conn);
```

I have two ways for searching the first one is quick search which takes what ever the user writes and search for it like this :

```
    string syn = 
@"select 
   name,
   pv,
   country,
   occupation ,
   type ,
   phone,
   mobile ,
   email 
from 
   guest 
where 
   name like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%' 
OR pv like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'
OR phone like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%' 
OR mobile like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%' 
OR email like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%' 
OR  country like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%' 
OR type like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%' 
OR occupation like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%' ";
```

When I apply the second query I get the results right but when I apply the first one I only get the name that comes first . I believe that there is something wrong with linking the tables in my database but should it be a problem to link using strings because using id is not suitable for my program right now?

Comment: Seems more like a data issue rather than syntax. If you comment out the `AND guest.name Like ...` where clause and run the query without it, do you get the same number of rows ?

Comment: Your code is wide open to SQL injection. Learn about parameterized queries, never, ever pass SQL parameters like that, it's terrible code. Not even for fun code. I can't emphasizes this enough, you're doing it VERY wrong. An example of how is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24191394/62829

Comment: @mattmanser: I see such comments all the time - while they make a correct claim, it has **nothing to do** with the question being asked !!! Imagine this is a sample from a course exercise... where sql injection plays no role whatsoever !!!  So please stop freaking out and relate to the questions being asked, so the user is helped, because that's the main purpose of this site !

Comment: @Veverke it's just a comment, and the issue it is pointing out is such an outdated and actively harmful practice that it should be banned from software development altogether. **Do not concatenate user input in your SQL strings, period**. This will even break when the user inputs a single quote (`'`). You're also misunderstanding the main purpose of this site, it is not a forum to help OP.

Comment: The queries are completely different, why should they return similar results?  Eg the first query joins multiple tables - if there are no matching records, nothing will be returned

Comment: @CodeCaster: I understand, and again, I agree that the observation is correct, there is no objection from my part - it is just annoying to see comments that do not relate to the question being asked, because it *pollutes* the thread. People enter the thread searching for answers, instantly.

Comment: @Veverke yeah and if nobody addresses the issue, and the Googler copy-pastes the answer, we have yet another application open to SQL injection. [SQL injection is the number one security issue in the world](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10), which sole fact merits addressing it in every question where it is visible.

Comment: I got busy discussing side issues - but as Panagiotis points out, the queries are different and thus comparing their results does not make sense.

Comment: @Veverke The need for such comments is justification in itself. If people understood how bad SQL injection is, they wouldn't write such code. Besides, it probably *is related*. This may well be responsible for the problem as well. An invalid input text *will* result in unexpected results at least. Unexpected string formatting of decimals and dates, *will* break queries.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: protection from SQL injection does not mean preventing the query to be filtered by the UI parameters. In other words, if an input is not validated, simply making sure it does not come with an embedded sql statement will not "fix" the results in any way. Whatever, I was just expressing an opinion. Am officially quiting the discussion now :-)

Comment: @Veverke actually it does - most similar questions have a  `somenumber.ToString()` or `someDate.ToString()`  statement that results in unexpected date values (DMY vs MDY), commas for decimals etc.

Comment: @mattmanser  this application has a special purpose where SQL Injection Doesn't matter at all , i have written previous questions and my code contained parameterized queries .This is not the issue right now and thanks for your notes :)

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos  I only mentioned the Second one to tell you that data is there and another query displays them and to point out to the idea of using a string as a key "which is wrong " and i mentioned that there are two records but it only displays the first one . even if  i swapped the data in my DB it  shows the one that comes first.

Comment: @Veverke as i noted data is not showing correctly and thanks for sticking to the point of the question :)

Comment: @RamazLoi the second query doesn't prove anything - it only proves that 1 of the 4 tables in the inner join have some values. For the first query to return anything, the *rest* of them should have matching values as well. You also didn't post the code that executes and returns the data - does it fill a DataTable, does it iterate over a reader?

Comment: @RamazLoi: Thanks Ramaz for making a point on objectiveness :-) !!! Back to your problem - if you omit the guest filter in your where clause, as I suggest above, do you see the record you are expecting to get in the results?

Comment: From @RoscaSebastian: how about trying using INNER JOIN command?

Comment: @RoscaSebastian This `FROM ,, WHERE ..` syntax is equivalent to an INNER JOIN. In order to return guests that don't have matching programs, hosts or episodes, a `LEFT JOIN` should be used.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a data-related problem but it's impossible to be sure without the code used to execute the query, or sample data. This answer is only an educated guess.

The first query performs an inner join between 4 tables, `guest`,`program`,`host` and `episode`. It is the equivalent of the following syntax which uses INNER JOIN and in fact, the original join format is now consider deprecated:

```
from 
   guest 
   inner join episode on guest.name=episode.guestnamefk
   inner join host on host.name=episode.hostnamefk,
   inner join program on program.name=episode.programnamefk
where 
   guest.name  Like '%someFragment%';
```

This query will return results only if there are guests whose name contains `someFragment` somewhere in them *ONLY* if all conditions match, ie the `guestnamefk` is exactly equal to `name`, `hostnamefk` is exactly equal to `host` etc. If there is even one character different, even a space in the beginning or end, the matching fails. Typically, matching doesn't take letter case into account and `John` matches `JOHN`, but not `John`.

Using names or any information that has business meaning as a key is a bad idea. If `name` is `John`, `guestnamefk` must *also* be `John`. If the first name is renamed, the change must cascade to all related records.

For this reason, surrogate keys are almost always used as primary keys, eg an integer field named `GuestId`. This allows you to change the guest name in the guest table only, without having to affect anything else.

If you want to retrieve guests even when there aren't matching episodes, hosts or programs, you need to use a `LEFT JOIN`, which returns all records from the left side and any matching records from the right, returning NULL if there is no match on the right. Using a `LEFT JOIN` is a very good way to debug failing INNER JOIN queries.

```
from 
   guest 
   left outer join episode on guest.name=episode.guestnamefk
   left outer host on host.name=episode.hostnamefk,
   left outer program on program.name=episode.programnamefk
where 
   guest.name  Like '%someFragment%';
```

If there is only one matching record across all tables though, only *that one* record will be returned.

You could try to check for all mismatches with a FULL OUTER JOIN. This will return null for non-matching records on the left and right. This will reveal whether, eg `guestnamefk` contains both a `John` and a `John` entry. The following query will return only the records that have *some* missing link:

```
from 
   guest 
   full outer join episode on guest.name=episode.guestnamefk
   full outer host on host.name=episode.hostnamefk,
   full outer program on program.name=episode.programnamefk
where 
   guest.name  is null
   or episode.guestnamefk is null 
   or program.name is null
   or host.name is null;
```

Another possibility is that the query is executed incorrectly. If, for example `ExecuteReader()` is used, the call to `Read()` may be missing. A missing brace could result in execution skipping over the call to `Read`. A call to `break,`continue`or`return` could terminate the loop prematurely. Again, it's impossible to guess without looking at the code.